# How to save decal position with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a way to store and reload the decals that produced in [This](https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/decal-splatter/) example ( [source-code](https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry)), so when a user "paints" a new splatter - he could save it and later on - reloads it.
I've tried many ways but unfortunately none of them seems to work.

My approach was to save the position, rotation and scale and then build them like this :

```
function loadLeePerrySmith(callback) {

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        loader.load('assets/LeePerrySmith.js', function (geometry) {

            geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
            geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;

            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/Map-COL.jpg'),
                specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/Map-SPEC.jpg'),
                normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/Map-NOR.jpg'),
                shininess: 10
            });

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            // ALL FOLLOWING VECTORS SHOULD COME FROM D.B
            var pos = new THREE.Vector3(0.18564199509178245, 23.11243036463454, 21.79273328636014);
            var rot = new THREE.Vector3(-0.24357513937426453, -0.07708039421506024, 4.358263365975027);

            var some = new THREE.Vector3(20.694949486021706, 20.694949486021706, 20.694949486021706);
            var check = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            var m = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.DecalGeometry(mesh, pos, rot, some, check), decalMaterial);
            scene.add(mesh);
            
            decals.push(m);
            scene.add(m);

            mesh.scale.set(10, 10, 10);


        });

    }
```

Comment: "I've tried many ways but unfortunately none of them seems to work."
This doesn't help us learn what the problem is. Please elaborate and explain the actual problem you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple timeOut did the trick

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    
        let m = new THREE.Mesh(new DecalGeometry(mesh, pos, rot, 
        size), decalMateria2);
        decals.push(m);
        scene.add(m);
            
},100)
```